# How to remove empty column or row in a org table with a function

Tags: org-mode, org-export, odt

When creating a table from a region, the empty column and row have to be deleted.

Comment: Could you give a small example with what you start with and what result you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a column (empty or not) by using `M-S-<left>` with the cursor in the column you want to remove.

Similarly, for a row, you can use `M-S-<up>` with the cursor in the row that you want to remove.

Do `C-h f org-table-delete-column` and `C-h f org-table-delete-row` to find out more about these commands.

---

Note that `M-S-<left>` and `M-S-<up>` are context-dependent bindings: they are bound to `org-shiftmetaleft` and `org-shiftmetaup` respectively, *not* to `org-table-delete-column` (or `-row`) directly. Each of these functions examines the context and dispatches to the appropriate command from there.

Do `C-h f org-shiftmetaleft` and `C-h f org-shiftmetaup` to find out what they do in other contexts. E.g. the doc string of `org-shiftmetaleft` says:

> Promote subtree or delete table column.
> Calls ‘org-promote-subtree’, ‘org-outdent-item-tree’, or
> ‘org-table-delete-column’, depending on context.  See the
> individual commands for more information.